# Flask : href link to html not working

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a basic Flask app with the following structure :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='E:\Programming\Python Projects\Flask')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('hello.html')
@app.route('/route/')
def route1():
    return render_template('route1.html')
app.run(debug = True,port = 8080,host = '0.0.0.0')
```

hello.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rendered!!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    The template has been rendered!!!<br>
    <a href="localhost:8080/route">Route No. 1</a>
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

route1.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Route No. 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>
    This is the first route!!!<br>
    Hello World!!!
</h2>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YQHsXMglC9A" width="853" height="480" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open `localhost:8080` it works fine.
But when I click on the link, it says :

```
The address wasn’t understood
Firefox doesn’t know how to open this address, because one of the following protocols (localhost) isn’t associated with any program or is not allowed in this context.
```

It works fine when I type the address `localhost:8080/route` manually in the address bar.
Also, it works fine when opened in a new tab.
I need help!!!
Thank You !!!

Comment: Can you try changing the link to just  `/route` making it relative instead of absolute? Alternatively you can add `http://` as a prefix making the link `http://localhost:8080/route`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `from flask import render_template, url_for`

and in the template:

```
<h1>
The template has been rendered!!!<br>
<a href="{{ url_for('route1') }}">Route No. 1</a>
</h1>
```

Just let Flask and Jinja2 make the URL's for you...

*It seems that you forgot the trailing slash at the link.
 Should be localhost:8080/route/
 But its  far better to use url_for as it avoids this type of problem